# What is the best way to integrate a report designer in a .NET application?

Tags: c#, .net, reporting

I need a solution in order to provide customers the ability to customize their own reports, without any IT knowledge. I need a designer easy to integrate with my .NET (C#) application.

What is the best solution/product, if any? Or should I consider to develop my own?

Thanks all,
G.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be [Report Builder,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155933.aspx) which comes with SQL Server.  You can produce a data mart or a data source view over your database.  If your application has a web front-end, you can fairly easily direct flow to the builder application.  For a rich-client it's a bit less cleanly integrated as you would have to spawn a browser and open it on the report model.

Another option in this vein is [RSInteract.](http://www.rsinteract.com/)  This is somewhat better than report builder, as it has better support for OLAP cubes.  It will consume (IIRC) RS reports, report models and cubes.

Answer (score 1):

[I posted this in a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491133/user-defined-reports-with-ssrs/499317#499317), but I'll put it here as well. It is a quick run down on what I had to do to achieve something similar.

> At my company I had to put together our own
>   Report Builder.
>
> We have about 30 or so Reporting
>   Service reports that our users can
>   access through the web or desktop
>   application. What we wanted to do was
>   give our users the ability to take any
>   given section within those reports and
>   create their own.
>
> If there is a report we have built for
>   them but they don't want to see the
>   graph, they can create the same report
>   with out it. If they want to combine
>   parts from 4 different reports to make
>   one summary report they can drag those
>   sections around on our custom builder
>   and save it.
>
> The report builder I had to put
>   together pulls down all the different
>   sub-reports they have chosen and reads
>   through the XML adding them to a
>   Report Builder Template XML file I
>   have created. I then have to aggregate
>   all the parameters so as to not ask
>   for them more than once (parameter
>   names do have to be unique across all
>   reports if you don't want them
>   aggregated). This new report XML is
>   deployed to the server and the users
>   can access them when ever they want.
>
> I've also given them the ability to
>   create their own cover pages, headers,
>   and footers by dragging text boxes,
>   images, global variables (date ran,
>   created, ran by, page number, etc...
>   anywhere on a blank canvas. I then
>   convert all the items they've drug
>   around and resized on this canvas in
>   to another report XML file and deploy
>   it as a sub-report that they can add
>   to their custom reports.
>
> Yes, this has taken quite a bit of
>   work, but our users love it. We're in
>   the process now of allowing them to
>   create a report with special groupings
>   so the report can be ran at different
>   levels.
>
> So it is possible, but there is no
>   easy answer. =) I'd be glad to give
>   advice to anyone who asks, but a
>   direct copy of the code is probably a violation
>   of my contract, but I'll do what I can
>   outside of that.